# What's the solution for nil.update_attributes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I'm unable to crack this error. Can't figure out why @customer is being assigned to value nil.

"You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.update_attributes"

Here is a snippet of the code :

```
def cedit
  @title = "Edit Customer Information"
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  if request.post? and params[:customer]
    attribute = params[:attribute]
    case attribute
      when "fname"
        try_to_update @customer, attribute
      when "email"
        try_to_update @customer, attribute
      when "add"
        try_to_update @customer, attribute
    end
  end
end


private
  def try_to_update(customer, attribute)
    if customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
      flash[:notice] = "Customer's details updated."
      redirect_to :action => "record", :controller => "c2"  
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure you are doing a post request and have a `customer` in the params, are you sure you're not looking for the `id`?

Comment: Why you are breaking the REST concepts? I suggest you to read a book about rails.

Comment: Yes I do have a customer in params. I'm using a similar code for another action and controller. It's working fine there..

Comment: Can you please tell me what REST concepts did I break? I'm new to RoR.

Comment: @mukul...are you sure this is the code..is there a typo in `@customer` anywhere where you are calling `try_to_update @customer, attribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code looks very none-rails like and breaks a couple of rails best practices. I would strongly recommend you read the [official Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and try to see if you can refactor some of your code.

I have too little information on what you are trying to do in the grand scale of things so I can't give you a full fledged answer. But you probably want to do something along these lines.

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
      flash[:notice] = "Customer updated"
    end
    redirect_to customer_path(@customer)
  end
end
```

The view could look something like this:

```
<%= form_for(:customer) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :fname %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :add %>
  <%= f.submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Good luck!